# File Input filling with data from URL

Tags: javascript, django, image, file-upload

At a form, I have a file input field (for image) and I want to add an optional way to fill this field by fetching data via ajax API and this returns me the URL of an image.

How can I set the content of the field input as the URL image, especially is it possible without passing a hidden a hidden text field to pass this image URL to the server?

Answer (score 1):

File inputs are for uploading the *content* of files from the client to the server. Since browsers won't let you (as a page author) download a file on behalf of the client, this isn't possible.

If what you were asking was possible, I could make you download a multi-gigabyte file just by making you visit my webpage. That wouldn't be a good situation to be in.

If you don't want the user to download and re-upload a file, then you don't want a file input. The other solution you mentioned (a field just containing the URL) sounds perfect for this.